# i can't install nx, it throws an error 'NX Missing Platform Dependency'

Tags: javascript, npm, nomachine-nx

when I ran npm install I got such a problem:

```
$ npm i
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-class-properties instead.
npm WARN cleanup Failed to remove some directories [
npm WARN cleanup   [
npm WARN cleanup     'D:\\Progects\\q\\apa-main\\node_modules\\@nx\\next\\node_modules\\@nx\\workspace',
npm WARN cleanup     [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'D:\Progects\q\apa-main\node_modules\@nx\next\node_modules\@nx\workspace\src\generators\ci-workflow\files'] {
npm WARN cleanup       errno: -4048,
npm WARN cleanup       code: 'EPERM',
npm WARN cleanup       syscall: 'rmdir',
npm WARN cleanup       path: 'D:\\Progects\\q\\apa-main\\node_modules\\@nx\\next\\node_modules\\@nx\\workspace\\src\\generators\\ci-workflow\\files'       
npm WARN cleanup     }
npm WARN cleanup   ],
npm WARN cleanup   [
npm WARN cleanup     'D:\\Progects\\q\\apa-main\\node_modules\\@nx\\webpack',
npm WARN cleanup     [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'D:\Progects\q\apa-main\node_modules\@nx\webpack\node_modules\@nx\js\src\generators\library\files'] {
npm WARN cleanup       errno: -4048,
npm WARN cleanup       code: 'EPERM',
npm WARN cleanup       syscall: 'rmdir',
npm WARN cleanup       path: 'D:\\Progects\\q\\apa-main\\node_modules\\@nx\\webpack\\node_modules\\@nx\\js\\src\\generators\\library\\files'
npm WARN cleanup     }
npm WARN cleanup   ],
npm WARN cleanup   [
npm WARN cleanup     'D:\\Progects\\q\\apa-main\\node_modules\\@nx\\next\\node_modules',
npm WARN cleanup     [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'D:\Progects\q\apa-main\node_modules\@nx\next\node_modules\@nx'] {
npm WARN cleanup       errno: -4048,
npm WARN cleanup       code: 'EPERM',
npm WARN cleanup       syscall: 'rmdir',
npm WARN cleanup       path: 'D:\\Progects\\q\\apa-main\\node_modules\\@nx\\next\\node_modules\\@nx'
npm WARN cleanup     }
npm WARN cleanup   ],
npm WARN cleanup   [
npm WARN cleanup     'D:\\Progects\\q\\apa-main\\node_modules\\@nx\\webpack',
npm WARN cleanup     [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'D:\Progects\q\apa-main\node_modules\@nx\webpack\node_modules\@nx\js\src\generators'] { 
npm WARN cleanup       errno: -4048,
npm WARN cleanup       code: 'EPERM',
npm WARN cleanup       syscall: 'rmdir',
npm WARN cleanup       path: 'D:\\Progects\\q\\apa-main\\node_modules\\@nx\\webpack\\node_modules\\@nx\\js\\src\\generators'
npm WARN cleanup     }
npm WARN cleanup   ],
npm WARN cleanup   [
npm WARN cleanup     'D:\\Progects\\q\\apa-main\\node_modules\\@nx\\node',
npm WARN cleanup     [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'D:\Progects\q\apa-main\node_modules\@nx\node\node_modules'] {
npm WARN cleanup       errno: -4048,
npm WARN cleanup       code: 'EPERM',
npm WARN cleanup       syscall: 'rmdir',
npm WARN cleanup       path: 'D:\\Progects\\q\\apa-main\\node_modules\\@nx\\node\\node_modules'
npm WARN cleanup     }
npm WARN cleanup   ]
npm WARN cleanup ]
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path D:\Progects\q\apa-main\node_modules\nx
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node ./bin/post-install
npm ERR! >  NX   Missing Platform Dependency
npm ERR!
npm ERR!    The Nx CLI could not find or load the native binary for your supported platform (win32-x64).
npm ERR!    This likely means that optional dependencies were not installed correctly, or your system is missing some system dependencies.
npm ERR!    For more information please see https://nx.dev/recipes/troubleshooting/troubleshoot-nx-install-issues

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\nnaza\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-10-20T19_48_42_135Z-debug-0.log
```

a couple of hours before I installed a new Windows on my PC, but on my other PC with the latest version of Windows 11 everything is working

can someone help me to find a solution to this problem

I tried to install different versions of node js, changing environmental variables, but it didn't help at all

Answer (score 2):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170

install that for Visual Studio 2015, 2017, 2019, and 2022 if you use Windows 10

Comment: What makes you think this is the solution?